# How can I hide an element only in PROD environments?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to target just PROD environment. How can I do that using
Angular code in my ts file?

```
<div *ngIf="environment != 'prod'" class="col-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary text-white add-photo" (click)="addPhoto()">Add Photo</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: [tag:angular] **is not the same** as [tag:angularjs].  You may receive incorrect or not applicable responses if you tag the wrong framework(s).

Answer (score 4):

Simply create a boolean flag in your class:

```js
isProdEnv: boolean;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isProdEnv = environment.production;
}
```

Then you can use `*ngIf` in the template.

Comment: how to target the environment in ts file? Seems its not working environment.prod doesn't   exist, and in my application environment.production is always true for all environments

Comment: My bad, it's `environment.production`. I've edited my answer. You import the environment constant from the environment file.

Comment: environment.production is always true in all the environments when I'm checking the code.

Comment: It should be false in environment.ts and true in environment.prod.ts